# Accessing VoltDB from Python

Tags: python, voltdb

Hi all I need to write a custom script in Python which will fetch data from one server and insert to another physical server even DB may be different like one will be Netezza other one will be Postgres/VoltDB .Everything is working fine except the VoltDB part.I am not able to find the driver for VoltDB to use with Python .I am using pyodbc for Netezza and Native Python library for Postgres .Can anyone help me to sort out things .VoltDB official site saying about Fastserializer I didn't understand the same 
Thanks
Anoop

Comment: Thanks for showing this .But I mentioned in the question about Fastserializer .After reading the same Github page I didn't understand how to add the same to my script Is it like importing whole module to my script ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one:

https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb-client-python

It does not need compilation.

Comment: That is correct (I work at VoltDB).  Some VoltDB client libraries need compilation but this one does not so the github repo has the same files as the official download (here: https://voltdb.com/community/monitoring-tools).  The VoltDB Python client library has it's own API, which uses a FastSerializer object to call procedures in VoltDB.  You can run Ad Hoc SQL statements by calling the @AdHoc system procedure.  The documentation is the README file on the repository.  There is also an examples folder with some examples.

Comment: Benjamin I checked the same solution . This FastSerializer is providing basic functionality.My problem is selecting data from one Physical DB as cursor and need to massage those data and need to insert into VoltDB.I may need to run all DDL DML SQL like we did in JDBC/ODBC drivers. For example for Netezza we "Pyodbc" Postgres we have "psycopg2"  after importing this module we can literally play with all SQL just like we are doing PLSQL